# Pass in a general class in a parameter

Tags: java

I have few classes which I would like to pass in as a parameter for one of my method. How would I get the classes variables after passing. For example, if I want to pass in a patient class, I want to know the patient name, phone number, etc. If I want to pass in a doctor class, I want to know the doctor's practice, name, etc. I want those information so that I could put them into a database. I was going to make several methods for each class, but was wondering is there a way to make one method and pass in a general class.

Here's my new code/ approach for the general method:

```
public boolean addNewUser(Object obj)
    {
        boolean success = false;

        int executedValue = 0; 

        try
        {
            Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();

            String query = "INSERT INTO Users (id, firstName, lastName, email, address, phonenumber, dob) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1, obj.getId); // not possible
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return success;
    }
```

Here's my old approach

```
public boolean addNewPatient(Patient patient)
    {
        boolean success = false;

        int executedValue = 0;  

        try
        {
            Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();

            String query = "INSERT INTO Users (id, firstName, lastName, email, address, phonenumber, dob) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setInt(1,patient.getId());
            stmt.setString(2, patient.getFirstName());
            etc...
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return success;

    }
```

Comment: Maybe have your classes implement an interface with a getAttributes method that returns an array of all the attributes you want? Since you want some classes to have shared functionality this doesn't seem like bad practice but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you can access the fields name type, etc of a class at runtime thru the reflection API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: This is exactly the case for an interface or base class.

Comment: Thanks @patrick-hainge, I'm going to try to implement the interface and see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through "**inheritance**". Since your database table is name "USERS" and looking at your code it looks like you are not differentiating between a patient user and doctor user, all goes in same table, so you can create a parent class as `User` and have all the common attributes like `id`, `firstName`, `lastName` etc. in it and then have `Patients` and `Doctor` class "extend" this parent class (with each sub class having more fields/methods specific to them). Then finally your DAO method will be `addUser(User user)`. For example, below sample class accepting `User` object.

```
public boolean addNewUser(User user) {
    boolean success = false;

    int executedValue = 0;

    try {
        Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();

        String query = "INSERT INTO Users (id, firstName, lastName, email, address, phonenumber, dob) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setInt(1, user.getId());
        stmt.setString(2, user.getFirstName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return success;
}
```

---

As an aside, you can also create a interface called as `User` and then let your `Patients` and `Doctor` class implement this interface, advantage of this approach is you are "**programming to interface**", but whether you should have parent class or an interface depends upon your application design and other factors, you are best to decide it, but having an interface is also an option. You can google code/program to interface to know more about it.

Comment: "Programming to an interface" is only partially related to the Java `interface`. Programming to an abstract base class is also programming to an interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create an interface, then let `Patient` and `Doctor` or any other object with the same attributes implement it.

```
public interface IUser{
    int id();
    String firstName();
    String lastName();
    String email();
    String address();
    int phoneNumber();
    String dob();
}
```

then change the `addNewUser` method to accept an argument of type `IUser`.

```
public boolean addNewUser(IUser user){
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now, you should be able to call all the methods from the `user` object through the interface.